# Items to move up dynamically

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

If I have a a number of  elements in one table column and I drag them one at a time to another column utilizing jQuery UI, how do I make remaining items in the first column move up, i.e. fill the gap left by the items that were moved. Assuming table cell valign="top".

I think it has to do something with DOM. It seems that even after I drag the item is it still in the same column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use jquery ui's sortable instead.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

You can connect lists and anything moved from one list will move the remaining elements to fill any gaps

However you are not giving us any code/markup to work with so I can only guess. Hope this helps!